# Definite integrals and infinite sums with known (conjectured) closed forms but no proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form

It appears that any infinite sum or definite integral with a nice closed form (like $\pi^2$ or $\sqrt{2}$) always has a proof. Are there any known infinite sums or definite integrals left, where the answer is known (or conjectured), but no one managed to make a proof yet?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Thank you